# How to retrieve an array of values from an array of ActiveRecord objects with 'each' method?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to perform this non-basic query with Rails :

```
proj_repartitions = ProjRepartition.includes(:proj_contributions).find( proj_project.proj_charges.each{|pc| pc.proj_repartition_id} )
```

The point is I need to pass an array of 'ids' to the `find` method.
I want to extract those 'ids' from an array of ActiveRecord objects where each of these is equipped with an 'id' attribute.

When I try on the Rails console:

```
proj_project.proj_charges.each{|pc| pc.proj_repartition_id}
```

I got exactly the same array as `proj_project.proj_charges`

What am I doing wrong?

=== UPDATE ===

According to the answers, **my definitive working code is**:

```
proj_project.proj_charges.collect{|pc| pc.proj_repartition_id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using each try map or collect - they should return an array.

Comment: Great ! It work with 'collect'. I'm still wondering why it doesn't work with each...

Comment: each is just a way of looping but doesn't return anything whereas collect returns an array. Any chance of a best answer?

Answer (score 1):

Each only executes the do block code for each item but doesn't "save" the return value.

Collect and Map executes the do block code for each item and the return value in an array.

hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
proj_project.proj_charges.map(&:proj_repartition_id)
```

Short way of writing

```
proj_project.proj_charges.map{|pc| pc.proj_repartition_id}
```